# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.activiti.engine.test.ActivitiRule

Tags: activiti, bpmn

I tried creating a JUnit test for a Activiti BPMN xml (right clicking and generating it). When I run the JUnit test am getting below exception. The class which is stated as not found is in activiti-engine-5.14.jar I tried searching and found a suggestion to use JUnit 4.11. I already use that as stated in the pom.xml below. Am new to activiti, please do let me know if anything needs to be changed to avoid below exception.

**JUnit test class:**

```
package org.activiti.designer.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.activiti.engine.RepositoryService;
import org.activiti.engine.RuntimeService;
import org.activiti.engine.runtime.ProcessInstance;
import org.activiti.engine.test.ActivitiRule;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestSimpleLeaveProcess {

    private String filename = "C:/Users/arun.bc/activitiws/activiti-sample/src/main/resources/diagrams/SimpleLeaveProcess.bpmn";

    @Rule
    public ActivitiRule activitiRule = new ActivitiRule();

    @Test
    public void startProcess() throws Exception {
        RepositoryService repositoryService = activitiRule
                .getRepositoryService();
        repositoryService
                .createDeployment()
                .addInputStream("SimpleLeaveProcess.bpmn.xml",
                        new FileInputStream(filename)).deploy();
        RuntimeService runtimeService = activitiRule.getRuntimeService();
        Map<String, Object> variableMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        variableMap.put("Empname", "Activiti");
        ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService
                .startProcessInstanceByKey("leaveProcess", variableMap);
        assertNotNull(processInstance.getId());
        System.out.println("id " + processInstance.getId() + " "
                + processInstance.getProcessDefinitionId());
    }
}
```

**Maven test logs**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: org.activiti.designer.test.TestSimpleLeaveProcess
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec <<< FAILURE!
initializationError(org.activiti.designer.test.TestSimpleLeaveProcess)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/activiti/engine/test/ActivitiRule;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2317)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1762)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:75)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.activiti.engine.test.ActivitiRule
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 23 more
```

**BPMN XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <process id="myProcess" name="My process" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:formProperty id="Empname" name="Empname" type="string"></activiti:formProperty>
      </extensionElements>
    </startEvent>
    <scriptTask id="scripttask1" name="Script Task" scriptFormat="groovy" activiti:autoStoreVariables="false">
      <script>out:println"ApplyforLeaveby"+Empname;</script>
    </scriptTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="scripttask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <userTask id="usertask1" name="H.R Approval" activiti:assignee="kermit"></userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="scripttask1" targetRef="usertask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="usertask1" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_myProcess">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="myProcess" id="BPMNPlane_myProcess">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="startevent1" id="BPMNShape_startevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="80.0" y="150.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="scripttask1" id="BPMNShape_scripttask1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="105.0" x="160.0" y="140.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="usertask1" id="BPMNShape_usertask1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="105.0" x="310.0" y="140.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="endevent1" id="BPMNShape_endevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="460.0" y="150.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow1" id="BPMNEdge_flow1">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="115.0" y="167.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="160.0" y="167.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow2" id="BPMNEdge_flow2">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="265.0" y="167.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="310.0" y="167.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow3" id="BPMNEdge_flow3">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="415.0" y="167.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="460.0" y="167.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sanjus</groupId>
    <artifactId>activiti-sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>activiti-sample</name>
    <description>activiti-sample</description>
    <properties>
        <activiti-version>5.14</activiti-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.168</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <classpathContainers>
                        <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/Activiti Designer
                            Extensions</classpathContainer>
                    </classpathContainers>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the NoClassDefFoundError `(java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/activiti/engine/test/ActivitiRule)` stated above by replacing Activiti version 5.14 with 5.17.0 in the pom.xml.

```
  <properties>
    <activiti-version>5.17.0</activiti-version>
  </properties>
```